# Sorting characters, how to stop repetition

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on an assignment where I have to take in a string and then display each character in the string. I figured out the code, but it's repeating. So, for instance, if the string is "aaabcd" it would print:

a freq: 3

a freq: 3

a freq: 3

b freq: 1

c freq: 1

d freq: 1

My goal is for it to only print the a once. Here is my code. Can someone help me find what I'm doing wrong?

```
char[] charArray = userSort.toCharArray();
            char tempChar;
            for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
                    if (charArray[i] < charArray[j]) {
                        tempChar = charArray[i];
                        charArray[i] = charArray[j];
                        charArray[j] = tempChar;
                    }
                }
            }
            String sortedString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
                userSort += charArray[i];
            }
            System.out.println(sortedString + "\n");
            int counter;
            sortedString = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
                counter = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
                    if (charArray[i] == charArray[j]) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                if (!sortedString.contains("Char: " + charArray[i])) {
                    if (sortedString.equals("")) {
                        sortedString += " " + charArray[i] + " freq: " + counter + "\n";
                    } else {
                        sortedString += " " + charArray[i] + " freq: " + counter + "\n";

                    }
                }
            }
                System.out.println(sortedString);
            System.out.println("");
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, that you use a `Map` to count how many times a character occured.

```
final Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
char[] charArray = userSort.toCharArray();
for( char c : charArray ){
    map.merge(c, 1, ( v1, v2 ) -> v1 == null ? v2 : v1 + v2);
}

map.forEach((character, frequency) -> System.out.println(character + " freq: " + frequency ));
```

Benefit is that everything gets really small and compact

Comment: Hey! Thank you, but I'm not allowed to use maps for my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Look at counting the result:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            counter = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
                if (charArray[i] == charArray[j]) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
```

As charArray is sorted (isn't it?), you can do:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            counter = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < charArray.length && charArray[j] == charArray[i]; j++) {
                counter++;
            }
```

Hence skipping the same chars:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; ) {
            counter = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < charArray.length && charArray[j] == charArray[i]; j++) {
                counter++;
            }
            ...
            i += counter;
```